# Comparing of the 2 lists of different objects but with a same fields

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine, comparison

I have a

```
class Player 
{
    public Vector3 position;
     public String name;
}
```

and a

```
class Field
{
    public Vector3 position;
    public bool isTarget;
}
```

I have a game with 3 players, 10 fields and 3 target fields. For winning, user should place all players on target fields. Is there a nice way for comparing 2 different objects lists (List< Player> and List< Field>) but with the same fields (positions) ?

Or should i inherit both Player and Field from

```
class BaseItem
{
    public Vector3 position;
}

class Player : BaseItem 
{
    public String name;
}
```

and compare `List<BaseItem>`?

EDIT: just to add some clarify: i have a List< Player> and List< Field> and i want to check if all of Players has the same position as all isTarget Fields. Order doesn't matter.

```
var listPlayer = new List<Player>();
listPlayer.Add(new Player { position = new Vector3(1,0,0); name = "a"; }
listPlayer.Add(new Player { position = new Vector3(0,1,0); name = "b"; }
listPlayer.Add(new Player { position = new Vector3(0,0,1); name = "c"; }

var listFields = new List<Field>();
listFields.Add(new Field { position = new Vector3(1,0,0);  isTarget = true;}
listFields.Add(new Field { position = new Vector3(0,1,0);  isTarget = true;}
listFields.Add(new Field { position = new Vector3(0,0,1);  isTarget = true;}
listFields.Add(new Field { position = new Vector3(1,1,0);  }
listFields.Add(new Field { position = new Vector3(1,0,1);  }
****
```

how can i run through all players and fields and see, if every player has a corresponding field (it should have equal position and isTarget should be true)?

---

SOLUTION: i'd like to keep Aybe's answer as solution, but i had finished algorytm so i'd like to share it in case it would be useful:

```
private void CheckIfWin()
{
    foreach (var target in gameboardTargets)        
        if (!IsAnyPlayerOnTarget(target))
            return;

    MessageBox.Show(HandleMessage,"You made it!", "Hooray!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}


private bool IsAnyPlayerOnTarget(Field target)
{
    foreach (var player in playersList)         
        if (target.GridPosition.Equals(player.GridPosition)) // can be replaced with BaseItem.ComparePosition()
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Please explain more clearer? Can you post a pseudo code of what you're trying to achieve? Also it is not clear what do you meant by *but with the same fields (positions) ?*

Comment: enumerate player list, inside enumerate field list, then compare player vs field position. Vary depending on your needs.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel updated a question

Comment: @LearnCocos2D lets just focus on a simplest case. I want to see how can i check if rule "every player should have a corresponding field (with istarget==true and field.position==player.position)" is satisfied.

Comment: use IEquatable<T> and LINQ Intersect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not sure whether comparing two different things is the right approach.**

You can however make these two things derive from a base class:

```
internal class BoardEntity {
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }
}

internal class Player : BoardEntity {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class Field : BoardEntity {
    public bool IsTarget { get; set; }
}
```

**Now there are other things emerging:**

- you'll have to cast them to base class every time which can get boring with time
- it is strange to compare two different things even if they do share the same property
- comparing `floats` is discouraged since the result can (will) be [wrong](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html)

Code:

```
internal class BoardEntity {
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }

    protected bool Equals(BoardEntity other) {
        return Position.Equals(other.Position);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        var other = obj as BoardEntity;
        return other != null && Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return Position.GetHashCode();
    }
}

internal class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
        var player = new Player();
        var field = new Field();

        BoardEntity boardEntity1 = player;
        BoardEntity boardEntity2 = field;
        bool b = boardEntity1.Equals(boardEntity2);
    }
}
```

**Suggestion:**

Providing a `ComparePosition()` method sounds more natural IMO, and since we cast to integers the comparison will be always correct.

```
internal class BoardEntity {
    public Vector3 Position { get; set; }

    public bool ComparePosition(BoardEntity boardEntity) {
        var v1 = new Vector3(boardEntity.Position.X, boardEntity.Position.Y, boardEntity.Position.Z);
        var v2 = new Vector3(Position.X, Position.Y, Position.Z);
        return v1.Equals(v2);
    }
}

internal class MyClass {
    public MyClass() {
        var player = new Player();
        var field = new Field();

        bool comparePosition = player.ComparePosition(field);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. Don't bother about floats comparing - i'm talking more general: how can i compare similar fields of the different object. I just dont feel a naive solutions to be right. Inheriting base objects seems fine, but maybe i can just implement Player.Equals(Field) method for comparing?

Comment: Actually, your suggestion seems reasonable.